# Choosing the post-build server based on variable value

Tags: ssh, deployment, jenkins

I have two server as a target machines: dev and production. They're both connected to the Jenkins by "Publish over SSH" plugin.

And now I want to choose which one is being used for a target. But in project configuration, the only thing I can do with target server is to use it as by choosing from fixed list which - AFAIK - is not parametrized.

What I want - as a parameter I choose dev/prod and - based on that choice - I want to specify a target machine.

Is it possible to achieve using pure-Jenkins solutions or plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the solution: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Flexible+Publish+Plugin

Will test and mark as accepted if it's correct.